# How big are document references?

Tags: mongodb

...and am I doing it wrong if I need to ask?

I have a data set composed of several thousand items (tracked objects in a video), each of which is composed of anywhere between 1 and about 100,000 other sub-items (data from each frame). I'm trying to figure out if it is wise to refer to every single frame within the object document, roughly like so:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("541e59c033e2931c587ad85a"),
    "frames" : [ 
        ObjectId("541e599b33e2931c587ad7f6"), 
        ObjectId("541e599b33e2931c587ad7f7"), 
        ObjectId("541e599b33e2931c587ad7f8")
    ],
    "track_id" : 124
}
```

My frames would be in another collection and look something like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("541e599b33e2931c587ad7f6"),
    "track_id" : 124,
    "frame" : 1
    "centroid" : [1234, 2345],
}
```

Because the length of `frames` in the "tracked" collection could extend into about the 100k range, I'm a bit worried I could scrape the 16 MB document size limit.

My [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) is that if all my frame data is plainly ordered with an integer, and unique between a `track_id` and `frame_no` combo, should I even bother with the document references?

Answer (score 0):

I think the field **frames** is redundant because all documents from collection **frames** can be collected by a certain **track_id**. It's safe to remove this field then you don't have the worry about BSON size limit any more.
By the way, this is so similar to **GridFS** which is supported by MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your title question: an [`ObjectId`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) is 12 bytes.

But it sounds like you don't need the `frames` references.  Add a unique index to the frames collection on `{track_id: 1, frame: 1}` which would let you quickly (and more easily) find any frame of any track.

Comment: I saw the 12-byte thing with some more searching, but is there any overhead for it being in an array?

Comment: @NickT Shouldn't be, no.